# PHP - send content directly from extern server to client without changing url

Tags: php, post

I couldn't come up with a better title, well follow scenario:

The client sends an API request to serverA.com, based on the userid he needs to get a json file from a specific server, let's say serverC.com

So far I'm using this code on serverA.com:

```
function redirect_post($url, $data, $headers = null) {
    $params = [
      'http' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
      ]
    ];
  
    if (!is_null($headers)) {
      $params['http']['header'] = '';
      foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
        $params['http']['header'] .= "$k: $v\n";
      }
    }
  
    $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
    $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  
    if ($fp) {
      echo @stream_get_contents($fp);
      die();
    } else {
      // Error
      throw new Exception("Error loading '$url', $php_errormsg");
    }
}

redirect_post('https://serverC.com', $_POST);
```

it works but I guess serverC.com sends the file to serverA.com first which then sends it to the client? If it's not the case and the user get's the content directly from serverC.com then how could I test it/make sure that that's the case?

But if it's not the case then is what I need even possible?

Comment: In the above code, serverC doesn't send anything to any specific server, it just responds to a request. What happens is that the client makes a request to serverA. During that request, serverA makes a server-side request to serverC (the client have no clue) and responds to it. The code on serverA then just echoes the response, which will be returned to the client. The client only knows about serverA and serverC just gets a request from serverA. What is your issue with this, since you say that it works? What is the actual question?

Comment: "The code on serverA then just echoes the response, which will be returned to the client" but this means that the entire content is sent to serverA first using bandwidth and then uses the same bandwith to send it to client or not? Which emans the content is sent TWICE in the process

Comment: Yes, serverA is getting the response from serverC, then the client gets the response from serverA. Unless the content is very large, it shouldn't matter. But if you don't want that, then you need to call serverC directly from the client and don't involve serverA at all.

Comment: But I need content to be sent directly from serverC to client back without going through serverA first. This is what apparently many websites like reddis 9gag and so on are doing, they have only one API url and the entire content of those websites is for sure not on one server

Comment: How do you know what they are doing in the background? How could you possibly know that if you call an endpoint in their API, that their server side code aren't calling many other servers/services and just relay the response back to the client? Most modern applications are doing just that, they have one single API which are calling other micro services in the background, just like you are doing on serverA.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to find out, if that what I'm asking in the question is possible then the possibility that this is how they are doing it is very high imo, at least it's the way I would be satisfied with

Comment: If the client makes a request to serverA, then it's only serverA that can respond to the client. That's how the web works. You make a request to a server, which then responds. ServerC doesn't know _anything_ about the client, nor should it. If serverA needs data from other servers, then serverA needs to make those requests and then return it to the client.

Comment: So it could be that they are using DNS round robin for let's say 10 servers for same API domain which only split the requests, those 10 servers requesting data out of let's say 1000 servers and so the data always goes twice until it reaches the client?

Comment: High traffic services usually have the DNS pointing to a load balancer, which distribute the requests to different instances. And the same for the micro services as well. And usually you use containers and spin up new instances when you need them. But this is starting to be a bit off-topic for the original question. You can set things up in many different ways. It's also off-topic for Stack Overflow since this site is for programming questions, not questions about networking or server architecture...

Comment: At least now I know that it can't be done that easy how I imagined it, I take a deeper look into load balancers. Thanks for your advisory!